# Can the 787 mini navigation display be controlled independently from the ND?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing-787, display

Some aircraft, e.g., the Boeing 787 have the option to display a "Mini Navigation Display" on the left Outboard Display Unit, right under the Primary Flight Display:

[image: Mini ND]
([image source](https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/nextgen/autopia/wp-content/gallery/787-cockpit/ana787cockpit16.jpg))

Is the information shown there a copy of the "normal" Navigation Display on the Inboard Display Unit (possibly with a limited set of information?), or can it be fully customized by the pilot *independently* of the other ND? (I'm not talking differences between left and right side PFDs/NDs, but I'm talking only one side, e.g. the left side only).

With "copy of normal ND" I specifically mean ALL updates to the ND via the EFIS control panel are reflected on both the ND and the mini ND. This would include wx, airports, range, modes (plan, arc, rose), etc.

In case of independent controls, how can the pilot customize the mini ND?

Answer (score 1):

The MiniMap is not an option, it's there as standard.

It's fixed at 20-miles range; the optional items are Wxr, Terrain and Traffic. The classic STA, WPT and ARPT from the ND are not available.

The MiniMap shows ADF needles, whereas the ND shows VOR needles.

The MiniMap looks like a development of the previous compass-rose at the bottom of the PFD, but it's mostly of little practical benefit. The major use of the MiniMap is to show Terrain while having Wxr on the ND, a dual-view that wasn't possible before.

Comment: so does that mean that the mini ND is not customizable beyond Wx, Terrain, Traffic?

Comment: Do you know how to turn on the Terrain and Weather Radar at the same time? I only see one set of buttons (WXR, TFC, TERR) on the glareshield.

Comment: I don’t know of any airplane where you can have Wxr and Terrain on the same screen at the same time. The system used to display the Terrain is the same as the Wxr - in effect the Terrain display is a created Wxr display. The nice thing on the 787 is the VSD (the profile view of the flight) which shows the terrain versus the pink string - much nicer than the MiniMap.